# How to start for loop again when it finished counting or when my index hits final value in java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

When my ALPHABET  List hit final value of 26 it breaks. I need that after it hits final value of 26, for loop start count again from zero.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] alpha = new char[26];
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        alpha[i] = (char)(97 + i);
    }
    System.out.print("Input char: ");
    char input= scanner.next().charAt(0);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
            if (alpha[i] == input) {
                System.out.println(alpha[i + 5]);
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: put the loop in a method and call it as much times as you need it to run

Comment: This might not be relevant to your problem, but the char matching might be redundant. if you are just looking to change the character by 5 spaces, get the ascii code, add 5 to it, then convert to string.

Answer (score 0):

Use **%** (Modulo) Operator.
`i` will start from `0` and whenever it crosses the array size, the `%` operator will make the value smaller.
For ex: when i=26, 26%26 = 0, so it will start traversing the array from the beginning.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] alpha = new char[26];
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        alpha[i] = (char)(97 + i);
    }
    System.out.print("Input char: ");
    char input= scanner.next().charAt(0);
    
    for (int i = 0;  ; i++) // <---
    {
        if (alpha[i % 26] == input) // <---
        {
            System.out.println(alpha[i + 5]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```